# How to use git with a config file different from $HOME/.gitconfig?

Tags: git, git-config

In addition to my standard `$HOME/.gitconfig`, I have an alternative "global" `git` configuration file, `$HOME/.gitconfig2`, that I prefer to use in certain circumstances.

I have not found a good way to tell `git` to use `$HOME/.gitconfig2` instead of `$HOME/.gitconfig`.  The best I have been able to come up with is to first create a suitable named symbolic link to `$HOME/.gitconfig2`, like this:

```
% mkdir $HOME/.githack
% ln -s $HOME/.gitconfig2 $HOME/.githack/.gitconfig
```

...and then invoke `git` like this:

```
% HOME=$HOME/.githack git ...
```

...thereby tricking `git` into looking for `.gitconfig` under `$HOME/.githack`.

Is there a better approach?

Also, is there a documented reason for why `git` does not provide a command-line flag (or even a dedicated environment flag) to override the location the a user's "global" (as opposed to per-repository) `git` configuration file?<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> My guess is that the reason for this is related to "bootstrapping"; e.g., it could be that, in order to process its command-line flags and/or environment variables, `git` first needs to read the user's configuration file, and therefore, it cannot use information in such flags or environment variables to determine the location of the configuration file.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to include a config file from your global config file : read the ["Includes" section of `git help config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_includes).

If your "certain circumstances" can be : "the git repository is located under a `$HOME/special/projects` directory", you can use :

```
[includeIf "gitdir:~/special/projects/"]
    path = ~/.gitconfig2
```